# Create a relation from list of Ids - Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

Is there a way to create a relationship using a list of ids?

I have done this for a single property like below:

```
builder.HasOne<Employee>()
       .WithMany()
       .HasForeignKey(x => x.EmployeeId);
```

But couldn't figure out how to do it if I have a list of `EmployeeId`.

Comment: A "relation" is not a "relationship", it is a set of tuples (i.e. a `TABLE` or `VIEW`). Whereas a "relationship" should be explicitly referred to by its constraint type (or lack-of), such as a foreign-key constraint. Please use unambiguous and precise terminology in future.

Comment: *if I have a list of EmployeeId* -- Please be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a database you don't create a Company table with a column with a list of Employee IDs... You either add a CompanyId to your Employee table for the company they belong to, or you create a joining table CompanyEmployee which links the two.

Entity Framework entities essentially represent relational data using objects. A Company can have a List of Employees (not employee IDs) where EF will work out (or be configured) to expect that the Employee will manage the FK reference back to its company.

```
public class Company
{
    [Key]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; } 

    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; } = new List<Employee>();
}

public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
  
    [ForeignKey("CompanyId")]
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

This is assuming you are using EF Core 6 (given .Net Core 6 tag) With EF6 you would either need to define the FK property for CompanyId or Map the shadow property with `.Map(x => x.MapKey())`  EF Core can manage this a bit better. EF works out the relationships, you don't need anything like trying to have a `List<int>` on Company for employee IDs.

Now if you happen to ever want to get the Employee IDs for a given company you can fetch that via the company or the employees:

```
var employeeIds = context.Company
    .Where(x => x.CompanyId == companyId)
    .SelectMany(x => x.Employees.Select(e => e.EmployeeId).ToList())
    .ToList();
```

or

```
var employeeIds = context.Employees
    .Where(x => x.CompanyId == companyId)
    .Select(x => x.EmployeeId)
    .ToList();
```